# Navigation Controller not work after using Present model controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I have an view with 3 buttons in that whenver user clicked on 1st button click it goes to seconViewController
Used this code.

```
PerformViewController * pvc=[[PerformViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PerformViewController" bundle:nil];

[self presentViewController:pvc animated:YES completion:nil];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

and another two  buttons i used the  `[self.navigationController pushViewController:gmavc animated:YES];`
 it works fine but when used tapped on 1st button clicked present the secondViewController.
and whne back to it's viw controller i used this code

```
ViewController *vc=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

After back to parant view controller my another two button push navigation controller not working not why this happening.

Comment: Did you give navigationcontroller to your rootviewcontroller?

Comment: yes it's working but when goes to prenetviewcontroller then back not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
{

}
- (IBAction)presentClicked:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)nevigateClicked:(id)sender;

@end



#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "PresViewController.h"
#import "NavViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)presentClicked:(id)sender {

    PresViewController *preView = [[PresViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PresViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:preView animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)nevigateClicked:(id)sender {

    NavViewController *navView = [[NavViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NavViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:navView animated:YES];
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks dude now work fine for me. post single answer at a time then comment wht you want to explain user. delete previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Define  `@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationCntr;` in YourAppDelegate

Use following code for presenting the controller

```
YourAppDelegate *del = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

YourViewController *viewCntrl = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

UINavigationController *navContrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewCntrl];
navContrl.navigationBarHidden = YES;

[del.navigationCntr presentModalViewController:navContrl animated:YES];
```

For dismissing

```
YourAppDelegate *delegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.navigationCntr dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    MainViewController *mainView = [[MainViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:mainView];
    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: ya i get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PresViewController : UIViewController
{

}
- (IBAction)hideClicked:(id)sender;


@end



#import "PresViewController.h"

@interface PresViewController ()

@end

@implementation PresViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)hideClicked:(id)sender {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NavViewController : UIViewController

@end


#import "NavViewController.h"

@interface NavViewController ()

@end

@implementation NavViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: this code is working for me, we can present view and then navigate also other view from same dashboard with different buttons.